# Should I build my file update logic into my unity project or leave it stand-alone?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A while ago I was working on an emulator project and I needed a way to update player files. I wrote up a little web patcher that automates http requests instead of the socket bindings because I didn't have a server at the time, just a web host. So, the way we ran it was you'd download the patcher/installer and this would gather your game files.

https://github.com/eqlogic/UOWebPatcher

However, since unity can use C#, I was wondering if I could build this type of logic into my game and update files through the games .exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can!**

Create a new Class that derived from `MonoBehaviour` then put your logic inside `Awake()` method. You can use [ScriptExecutionOrder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html) to ensure the script is always executed first.

Useful link: http://wiki.unity3d.com/wiki/index.php?title=Simple_TCP/IP_Client_-_Server

*But beware that Unity C# targets .Net 3.5. It means you cannot use features introduced after 3.5 or even C# 6.0 is not possible.*